# Is ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC application debugging available in MonoDevelop?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, mono, monodevelop

I've tried to debug sample ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC applications in MonoDevelop 2.4 (on Mono 2.8 on Windows 7) but breakpoints doesn't work.

If debugging MVC Application MonoDevelop prints the following into the output:

```
Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: An exception of type "Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException" thrown.
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive(CommandSet command_set, Int32 command, PacketWriter packet)
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Type_GetInfo(Int64 id)
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.GetInfo()
   at Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror.get_FullName()
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent(Event e, Boolean dequeuing)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEvent(Event e)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()
```

If debuffing ASP.NET application MonoDevelop silently finishes debugging after a second or two and sometimes leaves a hanging black console window (mono.exe).

Does anybody know is debugging of Web Applications supported by MonoDevelop? Or maybe how to make it work?

**Upd:** 
Also there are error messages in MonoDevelop log after each attempt to debug. In Mono 2.8 no errors appear but for older versions (2.6.7, 2.6.4) they are.

```
ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type '<Module>' loaded more than once

ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type '<Module>' loaded more than once

ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type 'System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim' loaded more than once

ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type 'TypeInfo__TypeMetadata' loaded more than once

ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type 'ChannelInfo__TypeMetadata' loaded more than once

ERROR [2010-11-03 17:32:47Z]: Type 'CrossAppDomainData__TypeMetadata' loaded more than once

OnTargetEvent, type - TargetExited
```

**Upd2:**
After looking throuth MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet sources i figured out that it supossed to work only with versions 1.0 & 2.0 of runtime. I've changed the runtime version of my test project but no changes...

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET debugging is supported with the soft debugger, but Windows support for the soft debugger has not been tested very much. In your specific case it looks like the targeted Mono runtime is crashing when in debugging mode. Could you [file a bug report](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Reporting_Bugs)?

Also, the upcoming MonoDevelop 2.4.1 adds support for debugging the 4.0 framework.

UPDATE: it looks like there is [a bug filed already](http://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=594193).

Comment: Thank you, Michael, so i'm going to figure out where is the problem and fix it. After a first look a filled bug doesn't seem to be very similar to my problem. To understand that i need to explore it more. As a result i'll fill a bug or commit a solution. Btw, don't you know, how soon MD 2.4.1 will be released?

Comment: Not sure, I expected it to be a few days ago :/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2#Debugger):

> There is initial support for ASP.NET debugging. This is supported only in Linux with the latest version of the Mono debugger or using the Soft Debugger backend.

So I guess debugging ASP.NET applications with MonoDevelop is still under heavy development.

Comment: Looking at the release notes of 2.4 nothing changed concerning ASP.NET debugging.

Comment: Hmmm... But it works for debugging Moonlight applications... I'm understand that there are some differences but none of them seems to be serious... Actually i have an idea that i have to initialize RemoteSoftDebuggerSession from AppDomain in which an application loaded... But i have no time to check it... Could it work?

Comment: And what about MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet.dll... It's existance in standard MonoDevelop 2.4 installation makes me think that AspNet debugging supossed to work... But in my hands it doesn't.